# In Pandas merge colum1 value with colum2, both col data type is object and only few values are null in first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data Frame is having two columns
Data Frame is having two columns

```
df1
col1 col2
 A    A
 B    A 
 B    A
 C    B
      C
      D
      E
 E    E
 F    G
      G
      H
      H
```

here both columns are object type, trying to merge value of column 2 with column 1 where column 1 value is null.
how to apply this for large dataset?I'm beginner for panads, trying to learn all the tricks here.

Expected output:

```
col1 col2
 A    A
 B    A 
 B    A
 C    B
 C    C
 D    D
 E    E
 E    E
 F    G
 G    G
 H    H
 H    H
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: small correction, all the avilable values which is in col1 need not be reaplce with '' or any other values, these need to be as it is,

extremly sorry this was missig before i edited the question

Comment: So `df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] == '', df['col2'])` working here?

Comment: no, it is returning value like for row 1 - > AA, row2 - BA,

Comment: hmmm, it seems you run `str.cat` solution

Comment: for this, i need to fill only the empty values from the col2, if values are already avilable in col1 then that values should not be changed

Comment: If check my answer it is exactly what do.

Comment: I think problem should be with data, what is `print (df[['col1','col2']].head().to_dict('l'))` ?

Comment: that solution is working at initial level testing, i m checking with more data

Comment: ok, so please change data sample by real data.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'], df['col1'], df['col2'])
```

Or [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) after first ensuring empty strings are represented as null values.

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace('', np.nan).combine_first(df['col2'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If empty values are missing values:

```
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    B    B
2  NaN    C
3  NaN    D
4  NaN    E
5    E    E
6    F    F
7  NaN    G
8  NaN    H
9  NaN    H

df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(df['col2'])
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    B    B
2    C    C
3    D    D
4    E    E
5    E    E
6    F    F
7    G    G
8    H    H
9    H    H
```

If empty values are empty strings:

```
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    B    B
2         C
3         D
4         E
5    E    E
6    F    F
7         G
8         H
9         H

df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] == '', df['col2'])
#thanks U10-Forward 
df['col1'] = f['col1'].replace('', np.nan).fillna(df['col2'])
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    B    B
2    C    C
3    D    D
4    E    E
5    E    E
6    F    F
7    G    G
8    H    H
9    H    H
```

Comment: If they are empty string you could also use `df['col1'].replace('', np.nan).fillna(df['col2'])`